# Update mongoDB document in bulk in C#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have multiple document like below in mongo collection(giving just one sample).

```
{
    "_id": "5fdb",
    "createddate": "2020-12-17",
    "orders": [
        {
            "_id": "4c65",
            "sourcesystemrecordid": null,
            "accepteddate": "2020-12-19",
            "fulfillment": [
                {
                    "_id": "7d3ceb",
                    "createdby": "Azekry",
                    "systemid": "123",
                    "systemrecordname": "source1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Under fulfilment, I want to update "**systemid**" value from "123" to "789" for all the documents where "systemrecordname" = "source1" and for that I have written below piece of code but the data is not updated. Can you help me on this?

```
foreach (var item in resultFromDatabse)
                {
                    var ordr = item.orders;
                    foreach (var e in ordr)
                    {
                        var actualval = "789";

                        foreach (var ef in e.fulfillment.Where(x => x.systemrecordname == "source1"))
                        {
                            filter = builder.Eq("systemrecordname", ef.systemrecordname);
                            var update = Builders<EquipmentDemandPlan>.Update.Set("orders.$[e].fulfillment.$[ef].systemid", actualval);

                            UpdateOneModel<EquipmentDemandPlan> updateOne = new UpdateOneModel<EquipmentDemandPlan>(filter, update)
                            {
                                ArrayFilters = new List<ArrayFilterDefinition> {
                                         new BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument("ef.systemrecordname", ef.systemrecordname))
                                    }
                            };
                            bulkupdate.Add(updateOne);

                        }
                    }
                }
                collection.BulkWriteAsync(bulkupdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

you only need `arrayFilters` in `$set`

```
db.collection.update({
  "orders.fulfillment.systemrecordname": "source1"
},
{
  $set: {
    "orders.$[o].fulfillment.$[f].systemid": "789"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "o._id": {
        $exists: true
      }
    },
    {
      "f.systemrecordname": "source1"
    }
  ],
  multi: true
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EGkMVHdwh96)

Comment: this is not the correct way since the the elements are nested so "orders.fulfillment.systemrecordname" will not work in C# code.

Comment: Use `$elemmatch` instead in C#, I just recommend a better way in mongo syntax.

Comment: c# driver supports providing a raw MQL into UpdateDefinition via implicit converting from string or BsonDocument